# PyCharm code completion gives outdated suggestions

Tags: pycharm, code-completion

I've been using the DyNet package for a while now.

Today I updated it the latest version (version 2.0, via 'pip install dynet').

The problem is that PyCharm's code completion still gives me the same suggestions as before, even though the package api has changed (some methods removed, some added).

For example, after the following code:

```
import dynet
m = dynet.Model()
```

code completion suggests the methods 'load_all' and 'save_all' which no longer exist (used to exist in the previous version I had installed, it no longer exists on my system). On the other hand, the method 'populate' (which didn't exist before and was added) doesn't appear at all in the suggestions (and when my mouse hovers over it, I get a popup saying 'Unresolved attribute reference').

I've tried to find a way to clear the code completion cache or force it to update, but everything I tried failed. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

In case it matters, I've encountered this problem on PyCharms version 2017.2.1 and 2017.2.2 and my interpreter is set as python on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), to which PyCharm connects via ssh.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `File > Invalidate caches / Restart`? Have you tried uninstalling are re-installing from inside PyCharm's install interface?

Comment: Tried both but neither worked

Answer (score 1):

This might be a DyNet bug. They say it's written in C++ with Python bindings, and it seems like the Python bindings might not have been updated properly (based on what you're saying)

If you look at the file [dynet_viz.py](https://github.com/clab/dynet/blob/master/python/dynet_viz.py) in their git repository you can see where they declare `class Model`. I don't understand the Python/C++ interaction, but I think this is where PyCharm is getting its information. You can see the methods `save_all`, `load_all`, etc. are there, and there is no `populate` method.

If you feel strongly about it I recommend filing a bug report to DyNet.

Note: I've never had DyNet installed prior to today, and I see the same behavior as you. I've also verified that I do indeed have version 2.0

Comment: Right, PyCharm takes the suggestions from `dynet_viz.py` but the actual code will run from the Cython-compiled modules.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with the remote interpreter. [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205813579-Any-way-to-force-a-refresh-of-external-libraries-on-a-remote-interpreter-) is what helped me. (second answer by dal),